# Не получается сделать адаптивность экрана 380px?

Tags: flexbox, media-queries

Не получается сделать адаптивность экрана 380px.

```css
* product_wrapper */


.product_wrapper {
 margin-right:  auto;
 margin-left:  auto;
 margin-top:  160px;
 justify-content: space-between;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 min-height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}

.pro_text {
 width: 530px;
 margin-left: 99px;
}

.hight_w {
 width: 131px;
 height: 25px;
 font-family: 'pt-sans';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 25px;
 font-size: 12px;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #1BB55D
}

.new_p {
 padding-bottom: 33px;
 width: 401px;
 height: 48px;
 font-family: 'pt_serif';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: normal;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #1E2529;
}

.pro_blog {
 width: 530px;
 height: 126px;
 font-family: 'pt-sans';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 31px;
 font-size: 16px;
 letter-spacing: 0.01em;

 color: #849299;
}


/* table */

.table_main {
 width: 147px;
 height: 32px;
 padding-top: 67px;
 padding-bottom: 17px;
 font-family: 'pt_serif';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: normal;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #1E2529;
}

.pro_text table {
 width: 449px;
 
}

.pro_text table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-style: hidden;
}
.pro_text table td {
 border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
 padding: 20px;
}
.pro_inner div{
 font-weight: 600;
}

.pro_bg {
 
 width: 682px;
 height: 500px; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
 .product_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 162px;
 }
 .pro_bg {
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 }
}
```

```html
  <div class="product_wrapper">
   <div class="pro_text">
    <div class="hight_w">Высокое качество</div>
    <div class="new_p">Наш новый продукт</div>
    <div class="pro_blog">Мы имеем все шансы войти в учебники по истории бизнеса, как пример смелости и инновационных решений, ведущих компанию к успеху. За 3 года, компания выросла на 78% как результат удачной работы команды. Мы владеем самым большим в Европе полем подсолнухов. 
    </div>
    <div class="table_main">Состав масла</div>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><div>884</div><div>Calories</div></td>
      <td><div>46 g.</div><div>Monounsaturated acids</div></td>
      <td><div>36 g.</div><div>Polyunsaturated acids</div></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><div>13 g.</div><div>Saturated Fat</div></td>
      <td><div>0 g.</div><div>Sugar</div></td>
      <td><div>0 g.</div><div>Cholesterol</div></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>

   <div class="pro_bg">
    <img src="images/pro_bg.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: самая большая проблема в блоке с текстом

Answer (score 0):

Используй вместо width свойство max-width! Тогда на маленьких екранах будет текст адаптироваться !

Comment: не работает!!!!!

Comment: Вы сами пробували так?